# Collecting commission on approve/transferFrom scenario

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Let's say I create an ERC20 token, and I want to collect 1,000 wei commission any time it replaces hands.

Here's Zeppelin transferFrom code:

```
function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }
```

Is this the right way to override it to achieve my goal?

```
function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    // make sure I can collect 1000 wei commission
    require(msg.sender.balance >= 1000)

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);

    // collect the commission (assume myAddress is set to my address)
    myAddress.transfer(1000);

    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }
```

And now can I assume whoever the `msg.sender` is, be it a smart contract (of an exchange perhaps?) or the `_to`, will have to pay additional 1000 wei on top of the gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of sending 1000 wei to some address via `myAddress.transfer(1000);` requires the smart contract to have received that payment at some point. This could even be in the same transaction but note that standard ERC20 transfers are not `payable`. Instead, I would suggest to collect your commission in tokens and not in Ether. Note that your code does not reflect the [current version of the OpenZeppelin standard ERC20 token](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/07020e954475a4fdd36e0252e88717b60f790b71/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol).

You could then extend the `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions as follows (note that I also use `Ownable` and the commission goes to the `Owner`):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./StandardToken.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";

contract CommissionToken is StandardToken, Ownable {

  uint256 public commission = 1000;

  // override
  function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(commission);
    balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(commission);
    return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
  }

  // override
  function transfer(
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(commission);
    balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(commission);
    return super.transfer(_to, _value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you modify balances you should emit a Transfer event.

Comment: What your answer suggest and is probably what I failed to understand is that `myAdress.transfer` transfers ETH from the contract's balance itself and not from the account that signed the transaction? I thought it takes the ETH from the account that signed the transaction... Is there a way to charge the account that signed the transaction? And how would it then be displayed to the end user in MetaMask?